# Prevent dcast from aggregating data

Tags: r, dataframe, dcast

I have data like:

```
rating       title
5            Bean
5            Bean
4            Bean
5            Bean
5            Egg
4            Egg
3            Bacon
2            Bacon
```

And I want to dcast like

```
dcast(data, rating ~ title, value.var="rating")
```

So the titles become the column headers, and the ratings for each title are listed below. However, every time it aggregates them instead, but I don't want this.

Comment: you do realize the result is uneven column lengths, right? if so, you do not mention (if you really want a data frame) what the missing defaults should be

Comment: SamPrice, how do you intend to identify first-row `Bacon` with first-row `Egg`? Typically in a `data.frame`, values on the same row are related to each other, but it's not clear from this data how the first Bean-5 would relate with any of the Egg values. In this case, if all you're looking for is presentation (just stack the values left-to-right), then that's a slightly different story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
read.table(text="rating       title
5            Bean
5            Bean
4            Bean
5            Bean
5            Egg
4            Egg
3            Bacon
2            Bacon", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(id = 1:n()) %>% 
  tidyr::spread(title, rating, fill = 0) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-id)
##   Bacon Bean Egg
## 1     0    5   0
## 2     0    5   0
## 3     0    4   0
## 4     0    5   0
## 5     0    0   5
## 6     0    0   4
## 7     3    0   0
## 8     2    0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll provide an alternative using `data.table`, in the chance that your use of `dcast` is meaningful. In slight contrast to the other answers, I wonder if you are intending this for *presentation* vice actual summary, since there is no apparent contextual correlation between the different ratings.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread('rating       title
5            Bean
5            Bean
4            Bean
5            Bean
5            Egg
4            Egg
3            Bacon
2            Bacon')
```

First we need to assign some "id" that is preserved in the pivot. Similarly, since this is for presentation (and we likely want blanks in the unused spaces vice `0` or `NA`), I'll convert the

```
DT$rating <- as.character(DT$rating)
DT[, id := seq_len(.N), by="title"]
DT
#    rating title id
# 1:      5  Bean  1
# 2:      5  Bean  2
# 3:      4  Bean  3
# 4:      5  Bean  4
# 5:      5   Egg  1
# 6:      4   Egg  2
# 7:      3 Bacon  1
# 8:      2 Bacon  2


dcast(DT, id ~ title, value.var = "rating", fill = "")[,id := NULL,][]
#    Bacon Bean Egg
# 1:     3    5   5
# 2:     2    5   4
# 3:          4    
# 4:          5
```

Note that this is not intended for calculations and analysis, merely for presentation. If you want to keep everything numbers, then you'll end up with

```
# starting with fresh `DT`, no as.character done
DT[, id := seq_len(.N), by="title"]
dcast(DT, id ~ title, value.var = "rating")[,id := NULL,][]
#    Bacon Bean Egg
# 1:     3    5   5
# 2:     2    5   4
# 3:    NA    4  NA
# 4:    NA    5  NA
```

or optionally use `dcast(..., fill=0)` to replace the `NA`s with `0`s.

(In this case, it is still not abundantly clear how the three values on any individual row relate to each other, but perhaps there's meaning in your real data/analysis.)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with `dplyr`& `tidyverse` package :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

data<-data.frame(rating=c(5,5,4,5,5,4,3,2),
                 title=c("Bean","Bean","Bean","Bean","Egg","Egg","Bacon","Bacon"))
```

**Code :**

```
data%>%mutate(dummy = 1:nrow(data)) %>% 
  spread(title, rating, fill = 0) %>% 
  select(-dummy)%>%t()
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
Bacon    0    0    0    0    0    0    3    2
Bean     5    5    4    5    0    0    0    0
Egg      0    0    0    0    5    4    0    0
```